# Multiple Class Styling Links

Tags: css

To further trim my css down I need to know how to style the links in multiple classes on one line for each link, visited, hover and active (unless there's a better way)

```
<div class="div1"><a href="">Some words</a></div>
<div class="div2"><a href="">Some words</a></div>
<div class="div3"><a href="">Some words</a></div>
```

Below is the css I thought would work but just the first column does '.div1' while .div2 and .div3 are ignored

```
.div1 a:link, div2 a:link, div3 a:link {
    color: red;
}
.div1 a:visited, div2 a:visited, div3 a:visited {
    color: red;
}
.div1 a:hover, div2 a:hover, div3 a:hover {
    color: blue;
}
.div1 a:active, div2 a:active, div3 a:active {
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Here's a fiddle link to help http://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/LUevH/

Comment: my bad, i was doing 3 different things at once to my stylesheet and mixed the problem up with another one and yea, problem solved. i need a break now to clear my head :D thanks to all who answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the dots before `div2` and `div3`.

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LUevH/1/)

Comment: Thanks Linek, I shouldn't have missed that. I lack caffeine :D

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it's not working is because you don't have dots at the beginning of the other divs in your css.

To simplify things, If you want the same style across multiple elements, create a class that is common to each:

```
<div class="div1 new"><a href="">Some words</a></div>
<div class="div2 new"><a href="">Some words</a></div>
<div class="div3 new"><a href="">Some words</a></div>


.new a:link, .new a:visited {
    color: red;
}
.new a:hover, .new a:active {
    color: blue;
}
```

If you don't need to reference the divs separately, then you probably don't need the div1, div2, div3 classes. If you do need to, then they may be better off as an ID.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jack, it was indeed the dots I was missing

Answer (score 0):

I's suggest organizing your markup a bit better. I'm presuming you don't want these styles applied globally, so I would suggest putting them into a semantic container:

```
<aside>
 <div class="div1"><a href="">Some words</a></div>
 <div class="div2"><a href="">Some words</a></div>
 <div class="div3"><a href="">Some words</a></div>
</aside>
```

Now you can apply your styles like this:

```
aside a:link, aside a:visited {
    color: red;
}

aside a:hover, aside a:active {
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll look into that aside stuff